# Why static_cast<> is returning -1

Tags: c++

I am working on a bug in an Application where acquiring data is not able to complete. Just assume it's one of the actions by the user and internally we are computing and displaying some information. The issue is occurring after migrating Visual Studio from 2010 to 2019.

I figured out the reason is because the below statement is returning `-1`, but I'm not able to understand why its returning `-1` instead of `-2570`:

```
int acqElevStartECount = -2302;
int accElevECounts  = 68;
int cvSettleCount = 200;

int startElevECount = static_cast<unsigned int>((double)acqElevStartECount - accElevECounts - cvSettleCount);
```

If I remove `(double)` from the statement, it works fine.

FYI, it's legacy code which was working fine in Visual Studio 2010. Moreover, I don't know why they are converting `int` data type to `double` then to `unsigned int`.

I wanted to know the reason why it is returning `-1`.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to convert an unsigned integer to a signed integer if the unsigned integer overflows. That's what is happening here. With or without `(double)` the value of the `unsigned int` is too big for an `int`. So either way I think the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I suspect it is because `-2570.0` is negative, and is undefined behavior to cast it to an unsigned int.  After you have undefined behavior, all bets are off.

Comment: Considering that all your inputs and your output are `int` you have to wonder why there is any casting at all.

Comment: That same code [returns 0 here](https://godbolt.org/z/eW9Y5n3bx). --  *The issue is occurring after migrating Visual Studio from 2010 to 2019* -- Also, your expectations of an upgrade of a compiler through 3+ versions to **not** have issues, were unrealistic.  Don't be surprised if there are other issues.

Comment: @john Isn't that implementation-defined(-but-always-works-in-practice) though? I don't think such cast is UB. It's the float->uint cast that's problematic.

Comment: `int startElevECount = static_cast<unsigned int>((double)acqElevStartECount - accElevECounts - cvSettleCount);` -- If I had to guess, there was some sort of usage of `double` close to this line of code, and the original coders forgot to change something on this line.  There is nothing I can think of as to why a programmer would deliberately do something like this.  In other words, a typo that was overlooked due to the program compiling without errors.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat To be clear, with double it's UB. But without, it would be well defined since C++20, and implementation defined before.

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted to know the reason why it is returning -1.

The floating point number has the value of `-2570` which is outside the range of representable values of `unsigned int`. Converting such floating point number to integer results in undefined behaviour. Don't do that.